# How to prevent a chrome extension from auto updating on Windows?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, updates

I realize there's a similar question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32943282/disable-update-of-specific-chrome-extension), however, the solutions no longer seems to apply. At least I'm not even able to find the directory they are referencing any more. (e.g. the "default" directory doesn't exist for me at:  `C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\**Default**\Extensions\<EXTENSION-ID>\<VERSION>\manifest.json`)

So for early 2022 (and late 2021) does anyone have a method to disable auto updates for a specific chrome extension? I would even take disabling auto updates for all chrome extensions if that were the only consistent option.

Comment: Perhaps try a [Windows build](https://chromium.woolyss.com/) of [Ungoogled Chromium](https://github.com/Eloston/ungoogled-chromium). With the "Marmaduke" builds (the self-contained "Archive" [7-zip](https://www.7-zip.org/) versions), the Chrome web store *should* be blocked by default. You can use [this extension](https://github.com/NeverDecaf/chromium-web-store) to "re-add" the ability to download items from the store (you may also want to see the Ungoogled Chromium wiki [here](https://ungoogled-software.github.io/ungoogled-chromium-wiki/faq)). However, I don't believe these will auto-update.

Comment: For me Default directory exists with the 21H1 build of Windows 10 and latest Chrome.